# undefined method `coffeeprocess' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting the above error when trying to reference an associated value from a different table.

I have two models with a one-to-many association.

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :processing

class Processing < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :roast
```

I have added a `process_id` column to the `Roasts` table.

`Roasts` represent an individual coffee roast, and `processing` represents one of three processes in the production of that coffee.

`Processing` is populated with three static strings, that I make available in the roasts form via a 'collection_select' field.

```
<%= form.collection_select(:process_id, Processing.order(:coffeeprocess), :id, :coffeeprocess, :prompt => 'Select Process') %>
```

I am able to assign a process to an individual roast, and I can see the corresponding ID in the `process_id` column.

However, when I go to the `roasts` show page, I get the error: `undefined method 'coffeeprocess' for nil:NilClass` which I understand is telling me the value is Nil.

I'm using the following in my show page.

```
<%= @roast.processing.coffeeprocess %>
```

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Comment: Fire up `rails c` and see if the `roast` in question really does have a `processing` object set.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `nil:NilClass` because Rails doesn't understand the relationship between Roasts and Processing.

Try

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :processing
```

See the [documentation for ActiveRecord Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more.

Comment: I believe it would be the other way round and have updated my OP.  However, I still get the same result either way.